# How to Plot Subsets of X,Y Lat Lon Points from a Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, geometry

I am able to plot a subset of lat/lon points using the code below and then I overlay a map (not shown).

```
fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,30))
gdf1.plot(ax=ax2,label='WIND FARM',marker='o',color='red',markersize=100,facecolors='red',zorder =10)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(dfp2['Longitude'], dfp2['Latitude'])]
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfp2, geometry=geometry) 
gdf2.plot(ax=ax2,label='Lightning 
Strikes',marker='o',color='black',markersize=50,facecolors='black',zorder =7)
plt.legend(fontsize=30,facecolor='dimgrey')
```

My data in the worksheet looks like this:

[image]

However, I need to plot a second plot of x,y points based on grouping the x,y lat/lon points by conditions of rows in columns. For example, i need to plot or assign to the "geometry" variable x,y points based on the "plant" = BAFFIN BAY. And, the same plot with another condition based on the column of data "Intensity KA" > 0.

I cannot find any examples of how to do this online. Thank you!

Comment: You mean using `Plant` and `Intensity` as `Hue` ?

Comment: hi - yes, so instead of plotting ALL the x,y lat/lon points, i need to get a subset of x,y lat/lon points based on "Plant"= ______ and "Intensity KA" = > 0. thank you!